# Pods not accessible (timeout) on 3 Node cluster created in AWS ec2 from master

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, centos

I have 3 node cluster in AWS ec2 (Centos 8 ami).

When I try to access pods scheduled on worker node from master:

```
kubectl exec -it kube-flannel-ds-amd64-lfzpd -n kube-system /bin/bash
Error from server: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.41.12.53:10250: i/o timeout
```

---

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   coredns-54ff9cd656-8mpbx         1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.244.0.7     master           <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-54ff9cd656-xcxvs         1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.244.0.6     master           <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-master                      1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.14.198   master           <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master            1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.14.198   master           <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master   1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.14.198   master           <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-8zgpw      1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.14.198   master           <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-lfzpd      1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.12.53    worker1          <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-nhw5j      1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.15.9     worker3   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-s6nms      1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.15.188   worker2          <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-47s8k                 1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.15.9     worker3   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-6lbvq                 1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.15.188   worker2          <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-vhmfp                 1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.14.198   master           <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-xwsnk                 1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.12.53    worker1          <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master            1/1     Running   2          7d21h   10.41.14.198   master           <none>           <none>
```

---

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME             STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
master           Ready    master   7d21h   v1.13.10
worker1          Ready    <none>   7d21h   v1.13.10
worker2          Ready    <none>   7d21h   v1.13.10
worker3          Ready    <none>   7d21h   v1.13.10
```

I tried below steps in all nodes, but no luck so far:

1. `iptables -w -P FORWARD ACCEPT` on all nodes
2. Turn on Masquerade
3. Turn on port 10250/tcp
4. Turn on port 8472/udp
5. Start kubelet

Comment: If you are using centOS (I assume you do since it's in the tags) there may be a problem with nftables backend centOS is using. Which version of centOS do you use?

Comment: CentOS_8(ami) @PawełGrondal

Comment: It's very likely your problems are because centOS uses NFT backend. You may need to change CNI to one that supports it e.g [Calico](https://www.projectcalico.org/)

Comment: @PawełGrondal you mean flannel won't work in this scenario?  or is there any way to disable nft and fallback to iptables...? any work around would be fine.

Comment: Yes, I believe flannel won't work, and unfortunately you can't fall back to iptables on centOS 8. You  should switch to Calico and configure it with `FELIX_IPTABLESBACKEND: NFT` environment variable.

Comment: @PawełGrondal ..ok...what about ubuntu and red hat....Do they also have same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232278/discussion-between-chris-vr-and-pawel-grondal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was because of inbound port in SG.I added these ports in SG I am able to get pass that issue.

```
  2222
  24007
  24008
49152-49251
```

My original installer script does not need to follow above steps while running on VMs and standalone machine.
As SG  is specific to EC2, so port should be allowed in inbound.
Point to note here is all my nodes(master and worker) are on same SG. even then port hast to be opened in inbound rule, that's the way SG works.

Answer (score 0):

Flannel does not support NFT, and since you are using CentOS 8, you can't fallback to iptables.
Your best bet in this situation would be to switch to [Calico](https://www.projectcalico.org/).
You have to update Calico DaemonSet with:

```yaml
....
    Environment:
      FELIX_IPTABLESBACKEND: NFT
....
```

or use version [3.12](https://www.projectcalico.org/whats-new-in-calico-v3-12/) or newer, as it adds
**Autodetection of iptables backend**

> Previous versions of Calico required you to specify the host’s iptables backend (one of NFT or Legacy). With this release, Calico can now autodetect the iptables variant on the host by setting the Felix configuration parameter IptablesBackend to Auto. This is useful in scenarios where you don’t know what the iptables backend might be such as in mixed deployments. For more information, see the documentation for iptables dataplane configuration

Or switch to Ubuntu 20.04. Ubuntu doesn't use nftables yet.

Comment: I can use redhat 7.9 also  ? I think nft is introduced in Redhat 8  ?.I will try let you know on this soon.

Comment: Hi @Chris_vr, have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: Its not working...I tried with CentOS_7...i am getting same issue. I am using flannel. I can't use calico as out package is uses flannel. @Pawel